# Join two dataframe with scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes:

- The first dataframe `DFNum` has 48 columns and 58500 rows.
- The second dataframe `DFString` has 7 columns and 58500 rows.

The columns of both dataframes are all different from each other. 
My goal is simply to join the two dataframes into one that has 55 columns (48 + 7) and always 58500 rows keeping the order they have before the join.

I made several attempts, also reading the other questions, but without success. In particular I tried:

`val df = DFNum.join(DFString)` and this give me the  following error:
`Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans. Join condition is missing or trivial. Join condition is missing or trivial. Either: use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations, or: enable implicit cartesian products by setting the configuration variable spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true;`.

Obviously with the cross join I get many more lines than I want: 58500 * 58500 rows.

Then I tried to edit the df adding an equal column `id` to both dataframes to join:
`val tmpNum = DFNum.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())`
`val tmpString = DFString.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())`

and use:

`val df = tmpNum.join(tmpString)`
and this give me the  following error:
`` USING column `id` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns:[...] ``.

I also tried several types of joins (all with both `tmpNum` and `tmpString` and `DFNum` and `DFString`) like:
`val df = tmpNum.join(tmpString, Seq("id"), "outer")`
`val df = tmpNum.join(tmpString, Seq("id"), "full_outer")` etc.
but I always get the same error `` USING column `id` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns:[...] ``.

(Obviously with `tmpNum` and `tmpString` the total columns of the new dataframe will be one more. Later I will drop the `id` column).

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Good idea to state what type of JOIn

Comment: Ok @thebluephantom Do you have a solution??

Comment: Of course, but what is the question? There are many JOIN types...

Comment: Tell me what allows me to get a dataframe that contains all 55 columns and 58500 rows, since I always get an error with "outer", "full outer" and "left"

Comment: join key to obviate Cartesian

Comment: sorry, but isn't that what i did and what i wrote above? Using Seq("id"). There the error is different

Comment: val df = DFNum.join(DFString)  no seq here

Comment: yes I understand, but read the whole question .. that was the first attempt and it didn't work. Later i added seq, but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: very cluttered question then...

Comment: Do you have a serious idea that I haven't tried already or do you just want to fool me? I do not understand..

Comment: i will look tomorrow

Comment: if add dummy ID to both dataframes then join will fail and no data will be returned. You probably get error because the column is dynamically generated. try to add ID column, save, read back and join. But you won't get any result because join will fail as data is different.

Comment: I believe no more assistance is required

Comment: What kind of assistance do you think you provided? @thebluephantom

Comment: none now as you have other helpers, pointless now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any key columns to join 2 dataframes, then you may depend upon `monotonically_increasing_id`

```
val a = Seq(("First",1), ("Secound",2), ("Third",3), ("Fourth",4)).toDF("col1", "col2")
val b = Seq(("india",980), ("japan",990), ("korea",1000), ("chaina",900)).toDF("col3", "col4")

a.show

+-------+----+
|   col1|col2|
+-------+----+
|  First|   1|
|Secound|   2|
|  Third|   3|
| Fourth|   4|
+-------+----+

b.show
+------+----+
|  col3|col4|
+------+----+
| india| 980|
| japan| 990|
| korea|1000|
|chaina| 900|
+------+----+
```

Then add a new column to both dataframes. Make sure that your dataframe sorted properly, otherwise after join dataframe data will mess.

```
val a1 = a.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
val b1 = b.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
```

Now do a join both dataframes by using `id` column then drop intermediate `id` column

```
a1.join(b1, Seq("id")).drop("id").show 

+-------+----+------+----+
|   col1|col2|  col3|col4|
+-------+----+------+----+
|  First|   1| india| 980|
|Secound|   2| japan| 990|
|  Third|   3| korea|1000|
| Fourth|   4|chaina| 900|
+-------+----+------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Two data sets can't be joined without matching data except using cartesian. The column names need not be same but the values in the column needs to be same. You can join 2 dataframes using all their columns if you need.

```
val df1 = //a data frame with columns col1-1, col1-2, col1-3
val df2 = //a data frame with columns col2-1, col2-2, col2-3

val dfJoined = df1.join(df2, df1.col1-1===df2.col2-1 or df1.col1-2===df2.col2-2 or df1.col1-3===df2.col2-3)

//Then drop one set of columns if they have same data.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this recently, with no success at all.  You can try converting the two objects to pandas dataframes and then do the merge.

Step #1:

```
df1= df1.select("*").toPandas()
df2= df2.select("*").toPandas()
```

Step #2:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Good luck!!

Comment: Interesting solution, although then I should transform the objects back into the spark dataframe. Thank you!